# Birt Designer 4.6.0 doesn't show preferences for plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, birt

I am using Birt Designer 4.6.0.

I have written a Plug-in that allows a user to set some global preferences
to export the template to a SFTP server via Window -> preferences dialog like (Host,login, password and port).

The issue I've run into is that preferences page doesn't show for this plugin, all others are shown, but not mine.

I tried my blugin in a standard eclipse, and it works.

Is this a bug in Birt Designer 4.6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unarchive the birt archive, do not execute the birt, have to add the Plugin first and after exexcute the Birt with the -clean option.

Birt.exe -clean